# How to prove the relationship between the leading $k$ eigenvectors and remaining eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $\mathbf{A}_{m\times m}$ is real symmetric and positive definite matrix. We employ SVD on A to get all orthogonal eigenvectors $\mathbf{u}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{u}_m$. Assume that $\mathbf{u}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{u}_k$ is the leading orthogonal eigenvectors regarding the leading eigenvalues. We make $\mathbf{U}=[\mathbf{u}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{u}_k]$. Could anyone prove the following formula:
$$
\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^T=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\mathbf{u}_k\mathbf{u}_k^T=\mathbf{I}-\sum_{i=k+1}^{m}\mathbf{u}_k\mathbf{u}_k^T
$$
I intuitively think that the above formula is false, but I cannot know how to prove it.

Comment: I know that $\mathbf{U}^T\mathbf{U}=\mathbf{I}_k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the matrix
$$
\tilde U = [U,U'] = [\overbrace{u_1,\dots,u_k}^U,\overbrace{u_{k+1},\dots,u_m}^{U'}]
$$
Note that we can write
$$
\begin{align}
UU^T &= \pmatrix{U & U'} \overbrace{\pmatrix{I_{k} & 0\\0&0_{m-k}}}^J \pmatrix{U\\U'} = 
\tilde U J \tilde U^T\\
\sum_{i=k+1}^n u_iu_i^T &= U'(U')^T 
\\ & = 
\pmatrix{U & U'} \pmatrix{0_{k} & 0\\0&I_{m-k}} \pmatrix{U\\U'}
= \tilde U (I_m - J) \tilde U^T
\end{align} 
$$
From there, use the usual matrix multiplication (and the fact that $\tilde U \tilde U^T = I$) to verify that
$$
\tilde U J \tilde U^T = I_m - \tilde U (I_m - J) \tilde U^T
$$
which is exactly what we wanted to show.

---

Another way to look at this is to note that we can rewrite the identity matrix as
$I = \sum_{i=1}^m u_i u_i^T$, then go through by manipulating sums rather than block matrices.

Comment: Do you mean that $UU^T=I_m-\tilde{U}(I_m-J)\tilde{U}^T=I_m-\tilde{U}\tilde{U}^T+\tilde{U}J\tilde{U}^T$? So the equation $\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^T=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\mathbf{u}_k\mathbf{u}_k^T=\mathbf{I}-\sum_{i=k+1}^{m}\mathbf{u}_k\mathbf{u}_k^T$ is false.

Comment: Because of $I_m\neq \tilde{U}\tilde{U}^T$

Comment: Can you give $U'U'^T$ in the final formula?

Comment: $\tilde{U}J\tilde{U}^T\neq I_m-\tilde{U}(I_m-J)\tilde{U}^T$

Comment: What do you mean $\tilde U \tilde U^T \neq I$?  The columns are orthonormal, so the matrix is orthogonal.

Comment: I mean $\tilde{U}^T\tilde{U}=I$, but $\tilde{U}\tilde{U}^T\neq I$

Comment: Do you understande me?

Comment: And I'm telling you that you're wrong. One implies the other since $\tilde U$ is square.

Comment: Can you tell me the theorem?

Comment: @DajiangLei for example, see the proofs given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/3852/81360)

Comment: I cannot say "thank you" enough. But I still have a problem, whether $\tilde{U}=[u_1,u_2,\cdots,u_m]$ is a orthogonal matrix? In linear algebra, an orthogonal matrix is a square matrix with real entries whose columns and rows are orthogonal unit vectors. I wonder whehter the eigenvectors matrix $\tilde{U}$ satisfy the above properties.

Comment: @DajiangLei the following theorem is often given directly after the definition of orthogonality: a square matrix $A$ is orthogonal $\iff$ $A$ has orthonormal columns $\iff$ $A$ has orthonormal rows $\iff A^{-1} = A^T$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I will conducte an experiment to prove the formula.